# Can i loop the Array elements in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Can I somehow loop all this things, so that it will not take so much space and solve the program.

I have around 600, such type of MYarray elements. Suggest me something.
how can  i loop all these things.

I tried using a for loop and if statement within that loop .but was unsuccessful

```
    Myarray(1) = Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(2, 1)
    Myarray(2) = Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(3, 1)
    Myarray(3) = Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(4, 1)
    Myarray(4) = Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(5, 1)
    ..
    ..
    Myarray(600)=Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(601, 1)
```

so that the loop will automatically continue until there are no values.

Please help me solving this as i am new to vba.

I am not too sure about it,I think we need  a for loop and a If loop with in FOR.  Not too sure about it.  Please help me do this
Thanks

Comment: You could put the range into a 2-dimensional array in one line of code rather than looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use code similar to:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Myarray(1 To 4) As Variant

    For I = 1 To 4
        Myarray(I) = Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(I + 1, 1)
    Next I
End Sub
```

pick your own upper limit.

**EDIT#1:**

If you want the **code** to pick the upper limit then:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim I As Long, N As Long
    N = Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    Dim Myarray()
    ReDim Myarray(1 To N)

    For I = 1 To N
        Myarray(I) = Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(I + 1, 1)
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: You just beat me to this. However I would use `I = Ubound(Myarray)`